# how to nicely stop all postgres processes

Tags: postgresql

How do you nicely stop all postgres processes with `pg_ctl` (or otherwise), when you don't recall what the database directory is, nor have the PGDATA environment variable defined?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's safe to:

```bash
sudo pkill -u postgres
```

That kills all processes running as user `postgres`. Or:

```bash
pkill postgres
```

That kills all processes named 'postgres'.

Do **not** use `kill -9` (`kill -KILL`). Just `kill` (without options) does a `SIGTERM`, which is what you want.

Alternatively, you can check the pgdata location if you can connect to PostgreSQL. For example:

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql -c "SHOW data_directory";
```

...or by checking its environment variables in `/proc/[postmaster pid]/environ`, where you identify the postmaster with `ps -fHC postgres`. Look for the one that's the parent of the other `postgres` processes. For example:

```
postgres   794     1  0 Nov06 ?        00:00:03 /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data -p 5432
postgres   857   794  0 Nov06 ?        00:00:00   postgres: logger process   
postgres   871   794  0 Nov06 ?        00:00:00   postgres: checkpointer process   
postgres   872   794  0 Nov06 ?        00:00:00   postgres: writer process   
postgres   873   794  0 Nov06 ?        00:00:00   postgres: wal writer process   
postgres   874   794  0 Nov06 ?        00:00:03   postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
postgres   875   794  0 Nov06 ?        00:00:07   postgres: stats collector process
```

Its datadir will generally be shown on its command line.

Comment: in that console output, there are two columns of numbers 871, 794 for instance.  Which one is the PID?

Comment: @mLstudent33 `cmd, pid, parent_pid, ...`

Answer (score 7):

It makes me nervous seeing kill and postgres in the same command. To answer the question using only `pg_ctl`, that would be:

```
pg_ctl -D $(psql -Xtc 'show data_directory') stop
```

The -X argument says to ignore the `.psqlrc` file. This is useful if you have psql configured to emit the time taken by a query (via the \timing command).

The -t argument says to remove the column name at the top of the output and the total number of rows produced.

The -c argument contains the SQL code to be executed.

Running a bare `psql -c 'show data_directory'` will probably produce the following output:

```
      data_directory
--------------------------
 /path/to/postgresql/data
(1 row)
```

Hence, backticking this through `$( ... )` will deliver `/path/to/postgresql/data` to the -D argument of pg_ctl, which will then stop the database in an orderly manner.

Comment: I guess, if this is officially meant to work, this should be the correct answer. Is it a new option?

Comment: This solution would benefit from explaining the options being used, as well as the usage of the `PGDATA` environment variable. My attempt at running this command resulted in a fail as there was no such database under my Linux user name.

Comment: `show data_directory` can be run without specifying a database, and indeed none of my servers have a database in my name. Nor does it require PGDATA, so I'm at a loss to explain your fail.

Comment: Using `kill` is safe with Postgres, but using `pg_ctl` is recommended to make sure associated processes are terminated along with it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/server-shutdown.html

Comment: ^ don't link to obsolete documentation. 9.3 was EOL 4 years ago.
Better: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/server-shutdown.html

Answer (score 2):

This work for me
ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5408501/248616

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'YOUR_NAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the command

```
systemctl stop postgresql
```

When you wish to restart it run

```
systemctl start postgresql
```

- It is likely these commands will require you to append `sudo`